# Android Client not receiving from Python Server (SOCKET)

Tags: java, python, android, sockets, server

I am new to programming and has been looking through tutorials for my project. Please forgive me if I may seem clueless about most things.

I am currently working on a project that requires an Android client to send string data to a Python server where the data will be processed and sent back from the Python Server to the Android client. I am using Socket and managed to send the data from Client to the Server and also got the Server to send it back to the Client. However, my Client isnt receiving anything, would anyone be kind enough to help me with this problem..?

These are my codes.

Android Client Receive:

```
 class recMsg extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.68.105", 8123);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String response = in.readLine();
            showToast(response);
            mTextView.setText((response));
            socket.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Python Server Receive and Send:

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = '192.168.68.105'  # this is your localhost
PORT = 8123

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# socket.socket: must use to create a socket.
# socket.AF_INET: Address Format, Internet = IP Addresses.
# socket.SOCK_STREAM: two-way, connection-based byte streams.
print('socket created')

# Bind socket to Host and Port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as err:
    print('Bind Failed, Error Code: ' + str(err[0]) + ', Message: ' + err[1])
    sys.exit()

print('Socket Bind Success!')

# listen(): This method sets up and start TCP listener.
s.listen(10)
print('Socket is now listening')

while True:

    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('Connect with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
    if not conn:
        break
    buf = conn.recv(4096).decode()
    print(buf)

    # convert string to byte and send back to android
    processedText = "Hello World"
    conn.send(processedText.encode())
    print("message sent")

s.close()
```

Comment: The only thing your client code does is trying to read a line. So how come you are telling us that the client can send data to the server?

Comment: Further you should show us the implementation of showToast() too.

Comment: You are reading lines but you aren't writing lines. Add a line terminator to the sent message. You are also trying to receive first in both client and server, which can only cause a deadlock. Sort out your application protocol. One side sends first, the other side receives first.

Comment: @blackapps I have left out the codes that send the data but I have confirmed that it worked as I could see the string output from the client shown in the "Run" log of my server.

"showToast":     
private void showToast(String message) {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

Comment: @user207421 by line terminator do you mean adding /r/n to inbetween lines? That makes sense but how can I do that(resolving the deadlock)?

Comment: You cannot display a toast using network code. It will crash your app.

Comment: `processedText = "Hello World"` should be `processedText = "Hello World\n"`.

Comment: `I have left out the codes that send the data..`. Post them. Post code in your post. Not in comments.

Comment: The line terminator for `readLine()` is documented as `\r`, `\n`, or `\r\n`. This doesn't have anything to do with resolving the deadlock, which is caused by the second issue I raised, as I stated.